# Getting the Column containing the non-english language in ORACLE

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

[image]

I have above entries in my database, my requirement is to extract the fields containing the non-english language characters ( including if the data containing the combination of english and non-english characters like HotelName field for the ID 45).

I tried by regexp_like function by looking for the alphanumeric and non-alphanumeric, but i have some data with combination of both the condition fails there.

Thanks in Advance

Raghavan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this do what you want?

```
where regexp_like(hotelname, '[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]')
```

That is, where the hotel name contains any character that is not a "letter" or digit.  You may need to take additional characters into account as well, such as commas, periods, and hyphens.

Comment: Thank you, Gordon this works, But I'm having the scenarios which contain the different combinations along with these non-English characters, like  海湾假日酒店-23. This condition is not including these strings.

Comment: @Raghavan . . . I'm glad you got it working.  I couldn't figure out why it wouldn't be working and I couldn't reproduce the problem.

Comment: Actually, with your query, I had added some more conditions regexp_like(hotelname, '[^a-zA-Z0-9.,!@#$%^&*()_^+"-= ]') to exclude english characters with symbols. Now I'm getting other language strings, but also the fields having the normal english alphabets along with control characters. Your query is base for this feature:). Now I need to split only the only characters with the other language characters